# Configure TableViewCell to play audio

Tags: uitableview, avaudioplayer, xcode4.3

I have an app that currently plays a 5 sec sound when a button is pressed within a view controller. I am trying to change this set up to where if I have a tableview, a specific cell is touched and the sound plays.  I do not want an action where you select the cell and it pushes to another window to play the sound. I simply want the sound to play on touch of the cell.

Currently for my button set up I had the following to play the sound in my view controller:

In the SoundLibViewController.h

// Identifying UIButton associated with sound file

```
-(IBAction)CarHorn:(id)sender;
```

@end

In the SoundLibViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)CarHorn:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"CarHorn", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
}
```

Unfortunately I can not find any help online to point me in the direction to change my code into incorporate a tableviewcell.

To give an example of what I'm looking to do:  You go into your iPhone/iPad and under settings you select "Sounds". Then you choose "Ringtone", which takes you to a list of sounds.  If you press the cell related to the sound it plays.  THAT is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this in your `UITableViewDelegate`

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSString * soundName = [self.soundNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]; // Assuming you have an array of sound names

        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)soundName, CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID); 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but this not what I'm looking for. I would like to take the existing code and rewrite it so that the cell when touched, will trigger the sound file like a button would with an IBAction.

Comment: I have a list of sounds that I want to play by touching the named cell. Based on the code above I assumed you meant that I would have to copy and paste this code for all the sounds.  Did I miss understand the code above?

Comment: indexPath.row will give you the index of the cell that was pressed. Then you can use that to play the appropriate sound. I've updated the answer.